# one project, many main classes, many jars with sbt?

Tags: scala, jar, sbt

I've been reading through the sbt doc, and can't find a good explicit example of this.

These are just simple little command line apps that are slight variations of one another and it's most convenient for my use case to just create different jars for each.

It looks like I just need to do something like this

```
packageOptions in (Compile, packageJar1) += ..

packageOptions in (Compile, packageJar2) += ..

packageOptions in (Compile, packageJar3) += ..
```

from (http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Howto/package.html)

and then set the main class in each one's manifest somehow? If that's the case how do I go about finishing wrapping this up? Otherwise, what do I really need to do?

Comment: have you found any good solution?

Comment: I've met the same problem with you, and I cannot solve it either. I hope anyone can give us a suggest.

Comment: May be this is related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22469218/how-can-sbt-generate-several-jars-with-different-classifiers-and-different-main